# I want create a layout for appointment (like google calender ) but how to add event layout?

Tags: android

I am working on creating a appointment application and design is like google calender. I am able to create a layout but not able to find a way to add events in perticular cells of layout.For reference I have attached a image and rounded event that I need to add it to layout.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [Android-Week-View](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View)

It is open-source library that provides calendar view with events. It allows to set many listeners on different events.[image: Week-View]